# Calculation for Battery Power Supply

Tags: batteries

I know a device I am making can run continuously using two AAA non-rechargeable batteries (namely Energizer Alkaline Max, at 5 volts) for X hours, and I'd like to provide advice on what rechargeable batteries the user can also use. (also AAA) How can I calculate which mAh-rated batteries will be needed for X hrs?

Comment: Well, you can either use one of the many, many available battery life calculators online, or you could google battery life equation and use that?

Comment: These calculations are **extremely simple** and you can easily figure them out by just trying to understand what a capacity rating (in Ah) stands for. There are also explanations to be found online like: https://www.powerstream.com/battery-capacity-calculations.htm  Your *Energizer Alkaline Max, at 5 volts* is unclear as these AAA cells generally provide 1.5 V, not 5 V.